# How to properly defang/disarm URLs with scheme ftp/ftps?

Tags: malware, antimalware

## No problems with: HTTP/HTTPS

When defanging/disarming URL schemes (e.g. with [python-defang](https://pypi.org/project/defang/)):

- `http` becomes `hXXp`
- `https` becomes `hXXps`

So, no problem here.

## But what happens with: FTP/FTPS/FXP

But how can these schemes be properly defanged?

- `ftp` becomes `fXp`

  - how do I know, if a given URL is defanged or if it's a real URL which just makes use of the [`File eXchange Protocol (fxp)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_eXchange_Protocol) instead of the normal `File Transfer Protocol (ftp)`?
- `ftps` becomes what? `fXps`?

  - what is the "official defanged" version of `ftps`?!
- `fxp` becomes what? `fXxp`?

  - what is the "official defanged" version of `fxp`?!

## Alternative?

Is there something like a rule of thumb for defanging/disarming: just to make sure that a URL doesn't work anymore within a browser so that the client won't open a malicious URL accidentally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link's source indicates it only supports HTTP HTTPS and FTP. Not SFTP, FTPS or FXP. Although support seems as trivial to add by updating the PROTOCOL_TRANSLATIONS list in **init**.py

FXP:// SFTP:// and FTPS:// are *not* supported in modern browsers. At best clicking such a URL will show an external application launch dialog. Similar to what you get with a magnet link.

As a rule of thumb; if crippling URLs is the goal. I would replace ':' with something else. Changing the protocol name itself doesn't make the url invalid, just unlikely to be understood/exist. It will still be parsed by extensions, plugins, etc, which may be enough to trigger bad mojo. Changing the colon will render them to strings.

Comment: The given example doesn't support it, that's correct. But there are more tools out there, e.g. [ioc_fanger](https://github.com/ioc-fang/ioc_fanger) (I looked at their tests and I think they don't support `ftp` at all but therefore they seems to handle a lot more cases of  "malformed" urls: e.g. `xxxx://` becomes `http://`.)

Comment: So I think how a URL becomes malformed isn't important. The only important think is that a browser can't understand and therefore can't automatically open a malicious URL, right? I think a common practice is also to surround dots with an invalid character, e.g.: `hxxp://google[.]com`